# HTML Dynamic grid that grows according to content and maintains proportions

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to implement a dynamic HTML Grid that grows based on content and maintains proportions.

When a cell content grows, it must grow and exceed the size of its own cell, it must push the growth of the entire grid (all cells) proportionally, possibly up to a max-width where it should begin to scroll.

[image]

I think I have tried everything, there are no minimum widths or heights, you must start from an empty grid with the cells and their proportions established, as an example, when placing content in the grid the grid must grow and expand the rest of its cells proportionally even if they have no content. (I just need to try to force the entire layout with JavaScript)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity and are there any other constraints eg a minimal width for the grid?

Comment: Not possible in CSS.